# MySQL not recognized when I try to run a hadoop job

Tags: mysql, windows, hadoop

I just installed hadoop 2.8.3 on Windows 10, I have mysql in my path and I can run it from cmd but when I run

```
hadoop jar C:/MapReduceClient.jar wordcount /input_dir /output_dir
```

it fails with

> Exit code: 9009
>   Exception message: 'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

I tried everything I could find online but nothing solves the problem. I can run mysql from cmd but I have no idea why it's not recognised by hadoop

Comment: Hadoop doesn't inherit your Windows CMD PATH, as far as I know

Comment: 1) Edit your question to add your code 2) Why are you using Mysql CLI from a MapReduce job instead of SparkSQL or JDBC anyway? 3) Capitalization matters. `MySQL` isn't the command.